# Clear-RecycleBin on remote computer fails

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.0

If I RDP to my Windows 2016 server (called LAUREL) and run this powershell, it works fine:

`Clear-RecycleBin -DriveLetter C -force`

However if I run from my Windows 10 workstation logged on as a Domain Admin, the command:

`icm -ComputerName laurel -ScriptBlock {Clear-RecycleBin -DriveLetter C -force}`

I get:

`The system cannot find the path specified
At line:1 char:1
+ icm -ComputerName laurel -ScriptBlock {Clear-RecycleBin -DriveLetter  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (RecycleBin:String) [Clear-RecycleBin], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToClearRecycleBin,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ClearRecycleBinCommand
    + PSComputerName        : laurel`

Any ideas on how to clear a recycle bin on a remote server? This snippet of powershell will be integrated into an automated VM build.

Comment: [This script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RecycleBinSize-092f15c7) maybe helpful.

Comment: Isn't the recycle bin per-user rather than per-computer? When invoking remotely, whose recycle bin should get cleared?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The account which has the security context of the remote connection.

Comment: Have you verified that's actually the case? (Unfortunately, wishful thinking doesn't cause features to spring into existence.) Just food for thought.

Comment: Yes with `icm -ComputerName laurel -ScriptBlock { gci env:username }`

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean that the `Clear-RecycleBin` cmdlet will work likewise (hence your question).

Comment: I can repro this, but don't see anything super obvious in the underlying code.  Interestingly, if you remove the -Force, you'll get a prompt to confirm the action, and no error after you confirm.  Not sure if it actually still runs the empty or not, but it's definitely weird.

Comment: Further, it looks like the recycle bin actually DOES empty, despite the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment, I'd suggest ignoring the error, using **-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue**

```
icm -ComputerName laurel -ScriptBlock {Clear-RecycleBin -DriveLetter C -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
```

Despite the error, at least in my environment, the recycle bin is actually cleared and ignoring the error will let your script continue.

I can repro this, but haven't figured out why yet - but will pass it along to the appropriate team. Interestingly, if you remove the -Force, you'll get a prompt to confirm the action, and no error after you confirm.

Comment: Seems to work fine, would be nice if this was cleaned up in a future release. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [issue closed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6743) which explains it is a bug in `ClearRecycleBinCommand.cs`

The bug finder recommends to use `Clear-RecycleBin -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to prevent irrelevant ErrorRecord.

This bug fixed in PowerShell v7.0.0-preview.6